# Parsing Facebook Graph API response

Tags: java, android, facebook, api

I'm working on Facebook Scores API for an android app. I query for the user score by accessing the user graph:

> `https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/scores&access_token={user_access_token}`

I get a response like:

```
{
 "data": [
{
  "user": {
    "name": "Michał Szydłowski", 
    "id": "100001699654797"
  }, 
  "score": 1200, 
  "application": {
    "name": "QuizzlePeople", 
    "namespace": "quizzlepeople", 
    "id": "176694722487191"
  }
}, 
{
  "user": {
    "name": "Michał Szydłowski", 
    "id": "100001699654797"
  }, 
  "score": 1, 
  "application": {
    "name": "Friend Smash!", 
    "namespace": "friendsmashsample", 
    "id": "480369938658210"
  }
}, 
{
  "user": {
    "name": "Michał Szydłowski", 
    "id": "100001699654797"
  }, 
  "score": 0, 
  "application": {
    "name": "Wordox", 
    "namespace": "wordox-the-game", 
    "id": "227993680602156"
  }
}, 
{
  "user": {
    "name": "Michał Szydłowski", 
    "id": "100001699654797"
  }, 
  "score": 0, 
  "application": {
    "name": "SongPop", 
    "namespace": "songpop", 
    "id": "323595464361460"
  }
 }
]
}
```

How do I extract useful data from this?

I'm trying to take something as a JSONObject, using:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();                
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=score&access_token=" + token);
        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(get);        
        Log.i("info1", resp.toString());
        // Parse the response
        HttpEntity responseEntity = resp.getEntity();
        String response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        Log.i("info1", response);
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray arr = result.getJSONArray("data");
        Log.i("info2", arr.toString());
```

just to see if I can take anything, say, the array named 'data'. Yet the logcat does not show me anything. It shows the first 2 logs, but not the 3rd. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use Facebook's SDK? That way the sample code will pretty much show you exactly how to do it

Comment: I do use it. But what sample code do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like JSONObject. You can loop thru it and do whatever you wish with the data. 
Have a look at http://json.org/ for documentation for a specific language (I presume you need java so click on the java link).

I appended the data to a table to give you an idea ( jquery / javascript ):

`fiddle:`http://jsfiddle.net/H8LNB/4/